# BimapImage PixelHeight and PixelWidth properties

Tags: c#, .net, image

Hi I am little bit confused about the `PixelHeight` and `PixelWidth` properties.

- Actually I wanted to is these `PixelHeight` and `PixelWidth` properties
  are equivalent to the Image `height` and `width` properties ?
- If not how are they related like how can i convert these pixelheight
  to image height and same for width ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the docs for [`Height`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource.height.aspx) and [`PixelHeight`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource.pixelheight.aspx), you'll see that `PixelHeight` is in pixels (obviously) and `Height` is in "device independent units", which are 1/96 of an inch.

You don't need to convert between them, since you have both available anyway.

Comment: I't is a requirement for me to convert.. do you know the relation between them ?

Comment: Sounds like a dumb requirement, since you have both values anyway. But see @ConnorsFan's answer.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage(v=vs.110).aspx), these two sets of values are linked by the resolution of the device. The Width and Height properties are in units of 1/96th inch. The relation would be:

```
PixelWidth = Width * dpiX / 96
PixelHeight = Height * dpiY / 96
```

So, if the resolution of the device is 96 DPI, the values are the same.